# Mapping & Calendar for Events

Tags: calendar, maps

There are many individual groups holding related events throughout my state, however attempts to create a shared calendar for them have not had all the features we'd like. We've tried shared Google Calender, Wordpress plugins, etc, and none have had all the features we'd like. We'd also like to avoid existing large sites like Meetup, as we'd like to only have our own events displayed on the Calender/Map. And we want to make sure individual organizers have full control over their own event's calender and can link to an existing Google Calender/iCalender feed. Ideally this could be ramped up for larger than state usage, but for now we're trying to replace a myriad of individual calenders spread all over the place, and a single Google Calender that attempts to gather them in being maintained by one person.

An example: Magic the Gathering has many individual groups and stores running events, with many individual organizers. Ideally the Calender/Map system would be able to pull in many individual calenders and display them in a shared Calender/Map with filtering by City, Region, and even by Event Sub Type such as Game Type, Ranked Games, etc. It should hopefully be embeddable on any other website and provide it's own (filterable by tags) export in standard calender formats. Game stores who already have web calendars would not have to do additional work since we can auto import their feeds.

Comment: Do you have any preferences for operating system or server requirements?

Comment: I've got linode ubuntu vps w/nginx+wp and windows flavors available, so wide range of options personally. The utility of this works for many event uses.

Comment: Are you fixed on the Google calendar – or would other options using open protocols (iCal) be an option, too? In the latter case, [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) might be an excellent option, as it allows you to share other resources as well.